# Electron ipcMain how to gracefully handle throwing an error

Tags: electron, uncaught-exception, ipcmain

In Electron if I throw an error anywhere on the backend it goes to a custom window. Trying to find a way to catch that to push to a custom area in my app I've found that I can detect the process with `process.on('uncaughtException')`. However I'm stuck trying to run a sender to send either the error or the report. What I've tried:

```js
ipcMain.on('main', async (e, data) => {
  try {
    await someModule(data)
    process.on('uncaughtException', err => e.sender.send('error', err.message))
    return e.sender.send('audit', 'No issues found')
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
})
```

module.js:

```
module.export = data => {
  throw Error('this is a test')
}
```

In the above I'm sending both get both error`and`audit` to renderer. I've researched for a way to pass 'uncaughtException' to a ternary but I'm not able to find any docs on how to condition for 'uncaughtException' but I did try:

```js
process.on('uncaughtException', err => {
  if (err) return e.sender.send('error', err.message)
  return e.sender.send('audit', 'test complete')
})
```

and the above only works if an error is present, research:

- [Catch all uncaughtException for Node js app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40867345/catch-all-uncaughtexception-for-node-js-app)
- [Nodejs uncaught exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50202507/nodejs-uncaught-exception-handling)
- [Node.js Uncaught Exception - Passing more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51566466/node-js-uncaught-exception-passing-more-details)

In Electron how can I intercept the error to pass it to renderer from main without throwing the default error window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use [`ipcMain.handle`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main#ipcmainhandlechannel-listener) you will be able to handle errors in the renderer process like this

```js
// Main process
ipcMain.handle('my-invokable-ipc', async (event, data) => {
  await someModule(data)
  return 'No issues found'
})

// Renderer process
async () => {
  try {
    const result = await ipcRenderer.invoke('my-invokable-ipc', data)
    console.log(result) // 'No issues found' if someModule did not throw an error
  } catch (err) {
    // you can handle someModule errors here
  }
}
```

**Update:** An issue with this approach is that the error emitted to the renderer process is serialized and it gets printed even though it's handled with a try/catch.

To fix this, you can also handle the errors in the main process

```js
// Main process
ipcMain.handle('my-invokable-ipc', async (event, data) => {
  try {
    await someModule(data)
    return 'No issues found'
  } catch (err) {
    // handle someModule errors and notify renderer process
    // return err.message or any other way you see fit
  }
})

// Renderer process
async () => {
  const result = await ipcRenderer.invoke('my-invokable-ipc', data)
  console.log(result) // 'No issues found' if someModule did not throw an error
}
```

Comment: Even though this approach works, it's not proper. The error returned is serialized. Also It prints out the error even if you catch it.

Comment: In that case, you should handle the error in the main process. I will update my answer.

Comment: But I would argue that's a massive inconvenience or a limitation to the user in utilizing IPC.

Comment: Maybe but what other options are available?

Comment: What I do is sending an object with the `error` property as the destructured error as the response. `error` will be `null` if there's no error.